# sliding drawer for iPhone like on Android

Tags: iphone, ios, slidingdrawer

Is there any ready Example for sliding drawer as on android.
NOT split view or menu scrolling from left to right, I need sliding drawer from bottom to top.

Thnks

Comment: Do you know about an ready example of sliding-drawer

Comment: I am trying to make an menu that will contain tabs and will be closes
By tapping/sliding on the arrow of the drawer the user will get this tabs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you can find the source code, this may help you

https://github.com/crocodella/PullableView

Comment: Thank you, maybe you know about similar example but with menu bar inside?